# whats the difference between java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out and java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout

Tags: timeout, server-sent-events

I encountered some problems. When I was looking at the online log, the sse connection communication reported an error about java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout, so I suspected that it was timed out when establishing the sse connection, so I wrote a demo locally and set the connection timeout to 1 millisecond. But its error is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out.

So when the error java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout occurs？

The exception is bellow:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at okio.SocketAsyncTimeout.newTimeoutException(Okio.kt:159)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit$jvm(AsyncTimeout.kt:203)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:163)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.kt:349)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.kt:222)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readHeaderLine(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:210)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:181)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:105)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:82)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:37)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:82)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:84)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:71)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.kt:184)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:136)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:204)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at okio.InputStreamSource.read(Okio.kt:102)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:159)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: just I want to know what time can the Watch Dog thread closes the socket in SocketAsyncTimeout#timeOut, is connect time out? or read timeout?